# Use bash awk sed to extract text field in file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file like this (odd lines and even lines have different type content):

```
try to upload UI/uploaded/2010.png
[{"index":"1","field":"file","exloc":"MiVip/07fb"}]
try to upload UI/uploaded/2011.png
[{"index":"1","field":"file","exloc":"MiVip/0487"}]
```

What I want to get is:

```
2010.png
MiVip/07fb
2011.png
MiVip/0487
```

And further more, I want the result be output into an array(for latter code use).
I want to use bash(awk,sed could be used if need) to do this.

When I use awk, I could not figure out the right regular expression for 
field separator(I want to use , space : " [ ] { and } for field separator, so the last field will be what I want).
The best answer will be giving the right separator for awk.

Or fallback to sed(replace all the , " [ ] { } to space).

Answer (score 3):

Easy in sed:

```
sed -e '/^try to upload/s=.*/==; /^\[/{s=.*"exloc":"==;s="}\]==}'
```

It uses so called "addresses", so it translates to: *If the line starts with "try to upload", remove everything up to the last slash. If the line starts with a `[`, remove everything up to `"exloc":"`, and remove the trailing `"}]`.*

Comment: further more, I want the result be output into an array(for latter code use).

Comment: @cox: Output is output. What do you mean? What programming language?

Comment: Bash programming language.

Answer (score 2):

give this awk one-liner a try:

```
awk '{c=$0~/\]$/?split($0,a,/"/)-1:split($0,a,/\//);print a[c]}' file
```

with your input example, it outputs:

```
kent$  awk '{c=$0~/\]$/?split($0,a,/"/)-1:split($0,a,/\//);print a[c]}' file
2010.png
MiVip/07fbde4d3abe340e22703f96494bf61e215995e3d
2011.png
MiVip/048734395a6442854877102d8f0a16ae4f642eaf8
```

This approach has used awk's `split()` function.  It checks the last char of each line in your input, if it ends with `]`, split with `"`, and print the `array[len-1]` otherwise we split with `/`, take the last element in array.

If the last char of your input should not be taken as target to check, you can change the `$0~/YourPattern/` to make the line work for you.

Comment: How could I put the result into an array, and use the array for further process at the END part of awk.

Comment: @cox then you don't `print`, put the result into an array,e.g. `result[NR]=a[c]` then do your processing in `END` block.